# Quad-CPU vs Dual-CPU AMD performance difference

Tags: performance, cpu, parallel-processing

important note: in this text - CPU is a CPU (processor, physical object) and CORE is a CORE (invisible, inside cpu)...

Quad-CPU systems are expensive, and there is not so many information about them.
(i of course not even dreaming about 4 xeons, talking about AMD only)

I had finally tested one and after 7 days of exploring it, my performance result looks like this:

```
1 CPU ****************(16ch)              <-good
2 CPU ************************(24ch)      <-ok
3 CPU ************************(24ch)      <-bad
4 CPU *************************(25ch)     <-bad (expected ~50)
```

(one star == one HD-h264 channel decoding, i have no doubts in test trustworthy... passmark sw from benchmark.com shows similar results)

So my conclusion is that QUAD-CPU is about 5% better than DUAL-CPU !!! ..and twice as expensive.

(test performed on: 4 x opteron6376, 64cores-total, supermicro-mb, win2008r2, and 1/2/3 cpu performed by turning of cores in msconfig->boot->adv.options->processorNumbers)

So, is there someone that can confirm me from OWN experience and knowledge either:

```
1)- THAT my result is ~OK, and that 5 or even 10% 
           is what QUAD-CPU only gives against DUAL-CPU.

2)- OR to say surely that my result (5%) is wrong, 
           and that i should continue exploring motherboard-configurations 
           and other possible reasons for performance-burst-failure,
           ... to reach/expect WHAT improvement value ???
```

???

(1) ... implies that QUAD-CPU is a fairy tale and no one should ever buy it. It is a lie about 'industrial super-fast machines' that in reality are beaten by one single intel-i7.

Comment: This question need at least one year research effort in cpu performances and video decoding stuff. What is the reason for downvote?

Comment: The effectively flat line from 2 to 4 CPUs (and 50% scaling with the addition of a CPU) hints that there is a lack of parallelism or some bottleneck. Under *ideal* circumstances (perfect NUMA optimization etc.) an extremely parallel workload like decoding as many streams as there are hardware threads should show nearly linear scaling at the CPU level (cache coherence overhead should not be bad at 4 CPUs with minimal actual sharing and memory bandwidth scales with CPU count *with perfect NUMA optimization*).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton well only thing about this i can play is disabling/enabling NUMA and WHEA in BIOS ... and test results was the same. But your comment leads to maybe correct conclusion that only very very SPECIFIC programs can benefit from 4cpu... for all others there is no reason to use it. which is maybe final truth

Comment: First software is unaware if its running on a "Core" or on a "CPU" that behavior is hidden everything except the operating system.  Even the operating system does not really care, its only worry, manage the processes so they complete every instruction.  I am not sure the reason you make this clarification in your question.

Comment: @Ramhound clarificaton is as 'termins used in this TEXT are...", to avoid meaningful answers of people that thought that i wrote CPU by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from cpu benchmark [list](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php) :

- SINGLE CPU amd opteron 6272: cpu-mark: **5104**
- DOUBLE CPU amd opteron 6272: cpu-mark: **9961**
- QUAD CPU amd opteron 6272: cpu-mark: **11028**

But there are probably 3ds-max or Maya users that buy quad-cpu, maybe they have other personal opinion about it...

Answer (score 3):

More CPU cores means the processor can do more things simultaneously.  They don't help with doing a *single* thing faster — though some programs can divide up big tasks into independent sub-tasks (called threads) that can be done simultaneously on several cores.

So, if you have four cores, but your computer only has enough simultaneous work to keep two of them busy, you're not getting any benefit from the other two.  On the other hand, if the workload can be divided up into at least four parts that are able to run simultaneously, those extra cores can provide a huge benefit.

You're right that four cores is overkill for the task of playing a single video.  But if you play that video at the same time as doing some *other* CPU-intensive tasks, they'll be able to run independently on separate cores instead of having to share time on the same core and slowing each other down.

Comment: Hm, but there was not 4 cores and one single video... there was 64 cores and 26 paralel video decoding with ffmpeg >NUL... 4 CPUs, with 16cores EACH.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd misunderstood your explanation of your performance graph.  Anyway, consider that your test may have encountered a bottleneck other than the CPU, such as RAM bandwidth or the throughput of your hard drive.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is first that i was suspect on, so i copied video on 26 copies, and made perfect test-script... but i have tested also with passmark sowtware on cpubenchmark.com and get nearly same result for cpu-points relation.

Comment: Still, though - 26 < 32, so you still have fewer videos processing than you have cores in a dual-CPU system. What results do you get for 64 videos at once?

Comment: @cpast it is a fullHD video, 20 seconds length. I am looking for a machine that can simultaneos decode X number of it for a total time less or equal to 20 seconds..... 64 videos are decoded in more than one minute.

Comment: @user1531897 But why would you expect this to make full use of 64 cores? Not every task is improved by throwing cores at it. If you just have 26 videos, and 4 CPUs doesn't help much, that means it isn't cost-effective _for your needs_. If 64 parallel tasks aren't substantially faster, that's a lot more relevant than 26 parallel tasks; even then, though, CPU speed is just one part of performance.

Comment: @cpast if i choose smaller size video (720p instead 1080p... i can perform test with 64 videos and everything would be as you expect from theory, 64 cores, 64 videos ... but ONE same cpu 6376amd can do about 40 of those...

Comment: Some workloads *will* get doubled performance going from two cores to four, but there are lots of factors besides number of cores that can affect performance of software, and there's not enough information in your question or comments to ascertain why your 4-core test didn't perform well.

Answer (score 0):

well for info purposes, a quad core could have 4 more 'logical' cores which gives more 'thinking power' to the processor, and a dual core can only have 2 'logical' cores

so is very probably that with more 'physical' cores the processing speed can be lower, but it will be computed more faster due the quantity of cores working on it at the same time